# electron-vue `No native build was found for platform=win32`

Tags: javascript

In my project, I use vue+electron,
but I want to use C++ dll file,so I import ffi-napi;

after run `npm run electron:build`,
i got this mistake;
[image]

according to `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder`  doc
[image]

i did it;

[image]

now development environment is normal, but product environment this mistake still exist,
so i need help.

Comment: Did you check for which platform is that DLL file for (64-bit/32-bit)?

Comment: yes, the dll is x64, my exe is x64 too

Comment: Is there some special configuration on your development environment which is not present in production? For example, C++ Redistributable installed?

Comment: No, I only added `ffi-napi`  related plug-ins to my development environment

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59275743 https://stackoverflow.com/q/68270429 https://githubmemory.com/repo/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/157

Comment: Please share the code with the right format instead images. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hey man , you were able to solve it ?